# (complex variables) Find roots of a complex variable such that $1+\omega^m+\omega^{2m}+ \cdots + \omega^{(n-1)m} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I need some help understanding the intuition behind the following question:

> Consider the root of $z^n=1$ given by $\omega = \cos\frac{2\pi}{n} + i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$. For which integers $m$ is $1+\omega^m+\omega^{2m}+ \cdots + \omega^{(n-1)m} = 0$?

What are they trying to get me to understand here? I can see that if $n=2$, then $m=1$ solves the equation since the root is at $-1$ in the complex plane. But for $n>2$, I have trouble understanding what to look for.

Comment: The powers of $\omega$ are evenly distributed along the unit circle. Think of them as unit vectors in the plane, and add them.

Comment: So then it's always true for $m=1$. But how to we reason for other values of $m$?

Comment: Go by cases. First of all, it fails if $m$ is an integer multiple of $n$. Next, if $m$ and $n$ shares any factors, what happens? Can you simplify? Lastly, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, what happens? Edit: do the last one second and the second one last.

Comment: Ahh... So then it must be true for all integer values of $m$ such that $m$ is not a multiple of $n$. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $w^m\ne1$ then using the geometric sum we get

$$\frac{w^{nm}-1}{w^m-1}=0$$
which's always true. So $m$ should be: $m\ne nk,\;k\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a little?

Comment: Notice that the given sum is the sum of geometric sequence with ratio $w^m$ so if $w^m\ne 1$ we verify that the equality holds and it's easy to see that 
$$w^m=1\iff m\in n\Bbb Z$$

Comment: In reading more about the geometric sum on the complex plane, I've come across some literature stating that the geometric sum fails when $\left| q \right| = 1$ in $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. Isn't this true in our case since all the points of $w^m$ are on the unit circle (meaning that $\left| w^m \right| = 1$)?

Comment: No it fails on your fraction only for $q=1$ since we can't divide by 0.